# Error starting application [Node version error]

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

How do I resolve this error for use or lower node.js version?

for stating, I did

```
NODE_ENV=production nodemon
```

or

```
nodemon
```

Error

```
Error: The module '/Users/pinkman/Work/MEAN/node_modules/bson/build/Release/bson.node' was compiled against a different Node.js version using 
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 44. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:672:18)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/pinkman/Work/MEAN/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js:15:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version/Users/pinkman/Work/MEAN/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:162
    throw new Error(msg);
    ^

Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
at /Users/pinkman/Work/MEAN/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:162:15
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Route.(anonymous function) [as get] (/Users/pinkman/Work/MEAN/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:158:15)
at Function.proto.(anonymous function) [as get] (/Users/pinkman/Work/MEAN/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:490:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/pinkman/Work/MEAN/app_api/routes/index.js:7:8)
at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/pinkman/Work/MEAN/app.js:10:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I tried everything with respect to

```
npm rebuild & npm install.
```

Nothings working! Please help!

Please avoid this ext this is to escape the overflow demand of more text!

---

Comment: Try updating your Node to latest version

Answer (score 0):

The error is basically telling you the bson package isn't compatible with whatever version of node.js you are running.

You can see which of your project's packages are outdated by running

`npm outdated`

Sometimes, these sorts of problems can be resolved by simply updating to the latest version of the package.

**Caution** *Blindly updating packages could introduce other problems.  Make sure you have a copy of your `package.json` in source control first so you can roll back if necessary.*

First run the following command

`npm update`

If that doesn't resolve the issue, it may be necessary to remove and reinstall the package instead.

```
npm uninstall bson --save
npm install bson --save
```

Comment: This didn't work though. I just had to do the entire process entirely. deleting node_modules and then starting again will installing all the dependencies.